# updateValue not working for Dictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, swift

I'm creating a test app using Swift in Xcode, and I've run into an annoying issue. I'm writing a simple class that will act as a cache using a Dictionary object. My implementation is below:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ImageCache {
    var dict:Dictionary<String,NSData>?;

    init() {
        dict = Dictionary<String,NSData>();
    }

    func exists(id:String) -> Bool {
        return dict!.indexForKey(id)!==nil;
    }

    func getImage(id:String) -> UIImage? {
        if(!exists(id)) {
            return nil;
        }
        return UIImage(data: (dict!)[id]);
    }

    func setData(id:String, data:NSData) {
        dict!.updateValue(data, forKey: id);
    }
}
```

The issue is in the last method, with Xcode stating "Could not find member 'UpdateValue'". This is weird, because the code hint seems to show it just fine:

[image: Code hint]

But when I try to compile:

[image: Compilation error]

Could this potentially be a bug in Xcode? Or am I missing something super-obvious?

Comment: Not to mention the typo in the method description, "if >they< key does not exist..."

Comment: Why are you using forced unwrapping? Shouldn't it just be `dict.updateValue()`?

Comment: @Chris No, because my "dict" variable refers to an optional type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is not a bug or a quirk in the compiler.

it is how `Optional` implemented (which may be flawed or not)

what happened is that the `Optional` store the `Dictionary` as immutable object (with `let` perhaps). So even `Optional` it is mutable, you can't modify the underlying `Dictionary`object directly (without reassign the Optional object).

`updateValue(forKey:)` is mutating method, you can't call it on immutable object and hence the error.

you can workaround it by doing

```
var d = dict!
d.updateValue(data, forKey: id)
```

because you copy the dictionary to another mutable variable, which then is mutable and able to call mutating method on it

but without `dict = d`, your change won't be applied on `dict` because `Dictionary` is value type, it makes copy on every assignment

[related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24096455/642626)

Comment: Excellent explanation, I believe this is a more acceptable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Smells like a bug or a quirk in the compiler.

I just tried something like

```
var d = dict!
d.updateValue(data, forKey: id)
```

and it works as expected.

Comment: Are you experiencing the same issue while trying to directly use "dict!"?

Comment: I can confirm your workaround works. Strange, hopefully they get that sorted out.

Comment: Same issue, I can confirm.