# How do I save JSON array of dictionaries in Swift that maps a String to an Int or String?

Tags: json, swift

I'm having a lot of difficulty with this one.

My server sends JSON arrays of dictionaries, with the dictionaries having a String as a key, with either a String or an Int as the value for the key. For example, if the key was name, it would return a string, but some values are asking for numeric things like "time since" which return Ints.

How do I handle this in Swift?

My first attempt was:

```
let dictArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as Dictionary<String, Any>[]
```

But I get:

> fatal error: can't unwrap Optional.none

If I change `Any` to `AnyObject` I can't cast it as an `Int` for some keys, it complains about the subscript.

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cocoa to Swift binding maps `id` as `AnyObject`. And since the keys are not guaranteed to exist in the dictionary, the subscript returns `AnyObject?`.

Along those lines still seems to be problem with Xcode beta2.
For example, this crashes reproducibly the swift REPL:

```
let a : AnyObject? = nil
let b : Any? = a
```

So that might be the reason as well, why casting to `Dictionary<String, Any>[]` does not work.

Either way you might be better off using the *"literal"* mapping `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>[]` and checking the types yourself.
When casting `AnyObject?` to `Int` you have to remember that you are [actually dealing with an optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24096828/3795188). That means you have to unwrap it first using `!` or an `if let` construct.

Alternatively you can just iterate over the dictionary:

```
var jsonError : NSError?
if var dictArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &jsonError) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>[]
{
    for dict in dictArray
    {
        for (key, data) in dict
        {
            var output : String = "(unknown)";
            if let number = data as? Int
            {
                output = "\(number)"
            }
            else if let str = data as? String
            {
                output = str
            }
            println("\(key): \(output)")
        }
    }
}
```