# Create a Dictionary as a optional property using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I created a swift class to test Dictionaries. So, I wrote the code below:

```
import Foundation

   class MyClass {

    var myFirstDictionary:[String :String]
    var myThirdDictionary:[String :String]?

    init(){
        var mySecondDictionary:[String :String] = [String :String]()
        mySecondDictionary["animal"] = "Monkey"
        mySecondDictionary.updateValue("something", forKey: "SomeKey")

        self.myFirstDictionary = [String :String]()
        addOneThingToSecondDictionary()
        addAnotherThingToSecondDictionary()

        self.myThirdDictionary! = [String :String]()
        addOneThingToThirdDictionary()
        addAnotherThingToThirdDictionary()
    }

    func addOneThingToSecondDictionary(){
        self.myFirstDictionary["animal"] = "Monkey"
    }

    func addAnotherThingToSecondDictionary(){
        self.myFirstDictionary.updateValue("Superman", forKey: "hero")
    }

    func addOneThingToThirdDictionary(){
        self.myThirdDictionary["animal"]! = "Monkey"
    }

    func addAnotherThingToThirdDictionary(){
        self.myThirdDictionary!.updateValue("Superman", forKey: "hero")
    }

  }
```

So, I got 3 errors referring to *"myThirdDictionary"* :

- In the Dictionary initialization compiler said: **Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments**
- When I tried to add a Key/value pair in **addOneThingToThirdDictionary()** : **'[String : String]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'**
- When I tried to add a Key/value pair in **addAnotherThingToThirdDictionary()** :  **Immutable value of type '[String : String]' only has mutating members named 'updateValue'**

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Which Xcode are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xcode Version 6.0 (6A267n) and OSX 10.9.4

Comment: Related: assigning value to optional dictionary in Swift. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096293/assign-value-to-optional-dictionary-in-swift?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of these issues are conceptual errors, and some of them have to do with behaviors that changed in today's Xcode 6 beta 5 release. Running through them all:

- This line compiles, but has a superfluous `!`:

  ```
  self.myThirdDictionary! = [String :String]()
  ```

  You don't need to unwrap an optional to assign to it -- it doesn't matter if its current contents are `nil` if you're providing new contents. Instead, just assign:

  ```
  self.myThirdDictionary = [String :String]()
  ```
- Similarly, this line fails because you're subscripting before unwrapping:

  ```
  self.myThirdDictionary["animal"]! = "Monkey"
  ```

  This is a problem because you could be subscripting `nil` if `myThirdDictionary` has not been initialized. Instead, subscript after checking/unwrapping the optional. As of beta 5, you can use mutating operators or methods through an optional check/unwrap, so the shortest and safest way to do this is:

  ```
  self.myThirdDictionary?["animal"] = "Monkey"
  ```

  If `myThirdDictionary` is `nil`, this line has no effect. If `myThirdDictionary` has been initialized, the subscript-set operation succeeds.
- This line failed on previous betas because force-unwrapping produced an immutable value:

  ```
  self.myThirdDictionary!.updateValue("Superman", forKey: "hero")
  ```

  Now, it works -- sort of -- because you can mutate the result of a force-unwrap. However, force unwrapping will crash if the optional is `nil`. Instead, it's better to use the optional-chaining operator (which, again, you can now mutate through):

  ```
  self.myThirdDictionary?.updateValue("Superman", forKey: "hero")
  ```

Finally, you have a lot of things in this code that can be slimmed down due to type and scope inference. Here it is with all the issues fixed and  superfluous bits removed:

```
class MyClass {

    var myFirstDictionary: [String: String]
    var myThirdDictionary: [String: String]?

    init(){
        var mySecondDictionary: [String: String] = [:]
        mySecondDictionary["animal"] = "Monkey"
        mySecondDictionary.updateValue("something", forKey: "SomeKey")

        myFirstDictionary = [:]
        addOneThingToSecondDictionary()
        addAnotherThingToSecondDictionary()

        // uncomment to see what happens when nil
        myThirdDictionary = [:]
        addOneThingToThirdDictionary()
        addAnotherThingToThirdDictionary()
    }

    func addOneThingToSecondDictionary(){
        myFirstDictionary["animal"] = "Monkey"
    }

    func addAnotherThingToSecondDictionary(){
        myFirstDictionary.updateValue("Superman", forKey: "hero")
    }

    func addOneThingToThirdDictionary(){
        myThirdDictionary?["animal"] = "Monkey"
    }

    func addAnotherThingToThirdDictionary(){
        myThirdDictionary?.updateValue("Superman", forKey: "hero")
    }

}
```

(Changes: `Foundation` import unused, empty dictionary literal instead of repeated type info)

Comment: That was very enlightening! Thank you rickster !

Answer (score 0):

Simple but effective

```
let like = (dic.value(forKey: "likes") as? NSDictionary)
print(like?.count)
```

Or if you want get complete Dictionary count then use:

```
 if let mainDic = dic as? NSDictionary{ 
    print(mainDic.count) 
    //add your code
}
```